# UIButton's title disappearing after transformation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uibutton, core-graphics

I have a strange problem. I have an UIButton with a custom background and one character as it's title. I would like the button to grow bigger with an animation. The animation works, however, I can't see the button's title anymore.

Here's my code:

```
UIButton *letterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[letterButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
[letterButton setTitle:[gameManager letterTextForIndex:curIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
letterButton.frame = CGRectMake(curX + kLetterButtonSize / 2, curY + kLetterButtonSize / 2, 0.01f, 0.01f);
[letterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedLetterButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButtonHighlight.png"]
                                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];

[letterButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[letterButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


[self.view addSubview:letterButton];

[UIButton animateWithDuration:0.20f delay:curIndex * 0.17f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^
{
     letterButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kLetterButtonSize / 0.01f, kLetterButtonSize / 0.01f);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
     [letterButton setTitle:[gameManager letterTextForIndex:curIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }];
```

As you can see, I start with a very small button and with a transformation, I make the button bigger over time. I calculate dynamically what's the scaling factor of my button.

Could anyone please explain to me why the button's title is not visible?

Comment: Have you check that `letterTextForIndex:` returns something?

Comment: Yeah I did, it does return a string, even when I hardcode a string as title, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way around: set a transformation for the initial state, and “un-transform” for the final state:

```
UIButton *letterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[letterButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
[letterButton setTitle:[gameManager letterTextForIndex:curIndex]
              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
letterButton.frame = CGRectMake(curX + kLetterButtonSize / 2, curY + kLetterButtonSize / 2, kLetterButtonSize, kLetterButtonSize);
letterButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01f/kLetterButtonSize, 0.01f/kLetterButtonSize);
[letterButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(pressedLetterButton:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
 UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButtonHighlight.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];

[letterButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[letterButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


[self.view addSubview:letterButton];

[UIButton animateWithDuration:0.20f delay:curIndex * 0.17f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^
{
    letterButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    [letterButton setTitle:[gameManager letterTextForIndex:curIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}];
```

It work for me in my test.

Generally, since `CAAnimation` came out, the best results for me have been always setting the final state of the animation, and using inverse transforms as the start state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great, thanks for the answer :) didn't see that it's also possible to do the reverse animation.